# Validation of Employee id using regular expression using Javascript/Vue.JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a REGEX for Employee Numbers.

The employee number must be a numerical value ONLY and must have a minimum of 8 values. The part after the hyphen can be optional but limited to two digits as below.

12345678
12345678-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\d{8}` => Starts with 8 numbers

`(-\d{2})?` => has optional ending of a dash followed by 2 numbers

`$` makes sure that the ending has to be either 8 numbers or the optional part after 8 numbers

```js
function validateEmployeeNumber(number) {
  return (/^\d{8}(-\d{2})?$/).test(number)
}

console.log(validateEmployeeNumber(12345678)) // true
console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("12345678")) // true
console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("12345678-12")) // true

console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("1234567")) // false
console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("123456789")) // false
console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("12345678-123")) // false
console.log(validateEmployeeNumber("12345678-")) // false
```

I never used Vue, but this should be fine:

```js
fd.field('Numeric').validators;
fd.field('Numeric').validators.push({
    name: 'MyCustomValidator',
    error: '',
    validate: function(value) {
        if ((/^\d{8}(-\d{2})?$/).test(value)) {
            return true; // Validation succeded
        }
        // You land here if it did not succeed
        this.error = 'Value is not valid';
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Maxmillian, thanks for replying. Is it possible for you to write this code in an IF statement please?

Comment: you want a funciton to be called with your number as input and return true if it fits?

Comment: edited it for you ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks again!

I have this code, how do I put it in this?

fd.field('Numeric').validators;

fd.field('Numeric').validators.push({
    name: 'MyCustomValidator',
    error: '',
    validate: function(value) {
        if (value <= 0) {
            this.error = 'Value must by greater than 0';
            return false;
        }

        if (value > 2000) {
            this.error = 'Value must be less than 2000';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});

Comment: where exactly do you need it? as one of your 2 if statements? is value the number that has to be validated?

Comment: At the moment the code is half way there...

I want it to check if the Value is <8 digits, which its doing.. IF True, return Error, else, No error.

IF the value is 8 digits OR has the -123 next to it, then its acceptable...

Retun Error for anything else.

Sorry, I'm not good at explaining things

Comment: Yes, Value is what needs to be validated

Comment: check the edit now ^^, I would appreciate an upvote and the mark for the asnwer <3

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot! You're Awesome! All the best! :)